# Can anyone give me reference from where this thing is written? (Statement from Mohini Murti)

Tags: women, reference-request

Can anyone give me reference to where this thing is written ? (The one referenced to Mohini Murti) (I got this from twitter)
[image]

Comment: Canto and verse from SB where this purport is referenced from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mohini devi does not say anything like that directly in the purana. That women likes to be exploited is a conclusion drawn by Swami Prabhupada in the purport and not direct words of Mohini murti.

But the next verse gives some idea on same.

This is stated in the next verse

> ŚB 8.9.10
>
> सालावृकाणां स्त्रीणां च स्वैरिणीनां सुरद्विष: । सख्यान्याहुरनित्यानि
> नूत्नं नूत्नं विचिन्वताम् ॥ १० ॥
>
> sālāvṛkāṇāṁ strīṇāṁ ca svairiṇīnāṁ sura-dviṣaḥ sakhyāny āhur anityāni
> nūtnaṁ nūtnaṁ vicinvatām
>
> Translation
>
> O demons, as monkeys, jackals and dogs are unsteady in their sexual
> relationships and want newer and newer friends every day, women who
> live independently seek new friends daily. Friendship with such a
> woman is never permanent. This is the opinion of learned scholars

Besides this I think there is no indication of any such statements by Mohini in the whole Bhagvatam text at all. The only other time Mohini appears in Bhagvatam besides samundra manthan is to give a view to Lord Shiva which leads to formation of gold and silver on earth.

Comment: Who has said these things ? I mean the verse that you quoted is spoken by whom ?

Comment: Mohini devi herself saying this to demons @river

Answer (score 1):

It is written in Manu Smriti 5:146

> बाल्ये पितुर्वशे तिष्ठेत् पाणिग्राहस्य यौवने ।
> पुत्राणां भर्तरि प्रेते न भजेत् स्त्री स्वतन्त्रताम् ॥ १४६ ॥

> In childhood she should remain under the protection of her father, in youth under that of her husband, and on the husband’s death under that of her sons; the woman should never have recourse to independence.—(146).

Same thig is written in Baudhayana Dharmasutra 2:3:45

> 45. Now they quote also (the following verse): Their father protects (them) in childhood, their husband protects (them) in youth, and their sons protect (them) in old age a woman is never fit for independence.' 45

Comment: Thanks .But I want the one spoken by Mohini Murti (avatar of Vishnu) that women like to be exploited by men